# The case to solve PDE as ODE

Tags: integration

I am not clear about the logic to determine the independent variable for the following integration constant.

The PDE in question is 
$$ U_{yy}=U_{y} $$   $ U_{yy}$ stands for $ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial y^2} $  and
$U_y=\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$ 
Let $Z=U_y$, then $$Z_y=Z$$ Separation of variable
$$ 1/Z \ dZ = dy $$ Integrating both sides
$$ \int 1/Z \  dZ = \int dy $$
$$ ln |Z| =y + f(x) \tag{1}$$ Here, I am not clear about the logic to use $ f(x) $ in stead of $ f(y) $. $\  $ Should it be $f(y)$? Further more, why $f(x)$ instead of a simple constant C. Anyway, I continue calculation.
$$ Z =e^{y+f(x)}$$  $$ U_y =f(x)e^y $$  $$du =f(x)e^y \ dy$$
$$ \int du = f(x) \int e^y \ dy $$
$$ u = f(x) e^y + g(y) \tag{2} $$
Is g(y) is OK? or should it be g(x).
Textbook tells me the logic behind is what independent variable is treated as a parameter.
  In case of (1), I seems to me x is treated as a parameter.
 in case of (2), I think x is again treated as a parameter.  Then it should be g(x) in stead of g(y)? 
Sorry for a beginner's question, but I appreciate your kind explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can think in reverse. Suppose $U(x,y)$ can be written as $U(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$, so $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=f'(x)$, it has nothing to do with $y$, right?  If $U$ is separable in variables, then when taking the derivative with respect to $x$, the parts that are independent of $x$ will be treated as constants when taking the derivative. So when we integrate, $0$ should be treated as the derivative of the function of the variables except $x$ when integrating. (2) should be $g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation.  This is my way of understanding the logic as explained by you.  When $ U(x,y) $ is taken derivative with respect to x, y has nothing to do and treated as the parameter.  Integration is a reverse operation of differentiation, or can be considered as (-1) order of derivative.  Therefore $U(x,y)$ is integrated with respect to y, x is the parameter, therefore the constants of integration is f(x).  As for my case (1) and (2), both integration is done with respect to y, and x is the parameter.  Constants of integration should both be the function of x.

Comment: Yes, you get it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way of understanding the logic as explained by Ychen.  When $U(x,y)$
is taken derivative with respect to $x$, $y$ has nothing to do and is treated as the parameter. Integration is a reverse operation of differentiation or can be considered as $(-1)$ order of derivative. Therefore $U(x,y)$
is integrated with respect to $y$, $x$ is the parameter, therefore the constant of integration is $f(x)$. As for my cases $(1)$ and $(2)$, both integration is done with respect to $y$, and $x$ is the parameter. Constants of integration should both be the function of $x$.